# :Python replace string not appearing after f append

Tags: python, string, for-loop, replace

```
        fin =  open(os.path.join(root, file), encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore',  mode='r')
        fout = open(os.path.join(root, file), encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore',  mode='a')
        data = fin.readlines()
        for line in data:
            thiscode = "<?php if (file_exists(dirname(__FILE__) . '/machine.php')) include_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/machine.php'); ?>"
            line = line.replace(thiscode, "")
            fout.write(line)
        fin.close()
        fout.close()
```

Hi, i am writing this part of my program where i need to delete a string text from a php file, i have tried different ways of opening the file and different for loops but the end result is still the part of the string is still in the php file. I even did a pdb.set_trace() into that line and reexecute the codes and i find them to be working until the write to file part where i cannot verify. I am only a beginner in programming so many thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you saying that you traced and saw `line = line.replace(thiscode, "")` remove the text from errant line? Can you make this a working program? You could have several dummy php lines for test.

Comment: i dont get you, what is wrong with that code?

Comment: You haven't given us data to test. And its not clear what you mean in your trace description. If that exact string is in the input line, it will be removed in the output. You could for instance put a print before and after the replace to see what happenss. Better, write some hacky test code instead. I did [this](https://pastebin.com/htGkbxz2) and the line was removed as expected. Perhaps your string is a bit different than you think, we can't know because we don't have that string.

Comment: the replace part is just what i would have wrote since i know only this code to replace, if you can do it better and more importantly it works, please share with me, and the file open and reading of text is also one of many ways to write, if you can do it better, share with me, i am not here because i am an expert, i am here because i only know this code and it is not working and i have basically no idea what went wrong. PS the replace part is not the part i am concerned.

Comment: To be 100% clear: if for example your input file contained **exactly and only** `<?php if (file_exists(dirname(__FILE__) . '/machine.php')) include_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/machine.php'); ?>`, then the code should result in an empty file? And you claim it does not? Or else can you give a simple, but *complete* example showing *exactly* how it is supposed to work? You can use a simpler version of the replace string, and just a few lines of text; but we need to see the *exact* input, *exact* expected output and *exact* actual output.

Answer (score 0):

The file you are reading and the file you are appending to are the same. Even if you remove the required text, it will be present in the same file in its original place. The new line (without the replaced text) will just be at the end of it.

So, create a new file (use `different filename` and `mode='w'` with `open()`), then write into that. Later you can rename it to the old file.

Answer (score 0):

i feel that 'r+' should have worked along with seek()(i.e rewind). but somehow it is not working. will investigate further.

**working!** myphp.php is the PHP file where need changes

```
with open("myphp.php","r",encoding='utf-8') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
thiscode = "<?php if (file_exists(dirname(__FILE__) . '/machine.php')) include_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/machine.php'); ?>"
with open("myphp.php", "w") as f:
    for line in lines:
        if line.strip("\n") != thiscode:
            f.write(line)
```

**not working:** similar which would have been a better way but this is not saving the data.

```
with open("myphp.php","r+",encoding='utf-8') as f:
    line = f.readline()
    while line:
        file_read_location=f.tell() #returns read location
        line = f.readline()
        if line.strip("\n") == thiscode:
            f.seek(file_read_location,0)
            f.write("")
            print("Changed!!")
            f.readline()
        print(file_read_location,line)
```